# Finding the roots of a polynomial with limited information

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $\ f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be a 7-th degree polynomial, such that.

$$
 f(0)=0 \land f(i)=-3i 
$$
$$
f'(0)=0 \land f'(i)=-21
$$

Find all the complex roots of $ f(x)-3x^7$. Find all possible factorizations of $ f(x)-3x^7 $ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$

The problem is I'm missing a root.

Let $g(x)=f(x)-3x^7$. It's easy to see that 0 is a double root of g. Also i and -i, because i is a double root too (no more than evaluating is required to reach this conclusion).

Then I have 6 roots: two times 0, two times i, two times -i. The next root must be real, because if not its conjugate should also be there and g(x) is a polynomial of the 7-th degree too, so that can't be.

But god knows I don't know how to find it. Even though the first part of the problem is done here, I still can't factorize the polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ if I don't have all the roots.

Any help?

Comment: One way to express the missing root is by dividing $f(x) - 3x^7$ by the product $x^2 (x^2+1)^2 $.

Comment: I think there are legitimately many different answers, depending on that last real root. Doesn't $g(x) = x^2(x^2+1)^2(x-r)$ work for every $r\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: @GregMartin:  I think that (modulo multiplication by a constant factor) you've answered the second part of the exercise ("Find all possible factorizations..."), and the OP essentially answered the first part ("Find all the complex roots...") if by *complex roots* is understood those roots which are not purely real.